# Azure ARM template give scoping access to different subscription

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have the following ARM template and I am trying to give scoping access to a subscription/resource group that is different from the subscription that I am currently deploying the ARM template. I [read this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-to-resource-group?tabs=azure-cli#deploy-to-target-resource-group) that talks about the scoping but I am not sure how to add the correct properties.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    },
    "publicIpName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "publicIpSku": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard"
    },
    "publicIPPrefixResourceId": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Resource Id of the PublicIpPrefix to create VM VIP"
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "name": "[parameters('publicIpName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('publicIpSku')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
        "publicIPPrefix": {
          "Id": "[parameters('publicIPPrefixResourceId')]"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Below is the sample code where you can check properties related **Arm Template** here

ARM template

```
  "parameters": {
        "vnetAName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the first VNET"
            }
        },
        "vnetBName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the Second VNET"
            }
        },
        "vnetAPrefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Prefix of the first VNET"
            }
        },
        "vnetBPrefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Prefix of the Second VNET"
            }
        },
        "subscriptionAID": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "the Subscription ID for the first VNET"
            }
        },
        "resourceGroupAName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "the resource group name for the first VNET"
            }
        },
```

- Go through this [document](https://dev.to/omiossec/using-scope-with-arm-templates-20co) for complete information.

Comment: Hey Node.JS, had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?